# SQL Stored Procedure Exception Not Found in JAVA

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, exception

Throwing exception from sql stored procedure catch block is not raising exception in java layer for SP1 while for SP2 exception raised.

When I am executing both SPs are giving exception in SQL Server but from java code I got no exception for SP1.

I am calling both SPs using JPA StoredProcedureQuery and using Hibernate & Spring.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 1/0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
THROW 50001, @ErrorMessage, 1;
END CATCH


CREATE PROCEDURE SP2
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 1/0
if @@error<>0
GOTO Erro

RETURN
Erro:
THROW 50001, @ErrorMessage, 1;
```

I have tested that if I use any THROW in TRY block it raise exception in Java side while in CATCH block its not.

Comment: I have also seen the post here [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic844622-23-1.aspx) but answer doesn't convince me. Does java really not support SQL Try-Catch?

Comment: Share resut of `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id = 50001`

Comment: and if you try invoking using a JDBC CallableStatement?

Comment: @lad2025 result is null means no row returned. But I don't think that matters because THROW without any parameter should raise exception.

Comment: @NeilStockton I didn't try to invoke JDBC CallableStatement.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do this @NeilStockton. Would you provide any link?

Comment: Go to an internet search engine and type in "JDBC CallableStatement tutorial" ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101052/discussion-between-tanjim-rahman-and-neil-stockton).